# Unable to open any file from explorer after connecting FTP

Tags: windows-explorer, ftp

We have uploaded the file through **FTP** by using FTP details programmatically. And it is opening the file when we are opening the **shared folder** or by going to the **local drive**.

But not open when we connect **FTP** from **Explorer** and it asks **"How do you want to open this?"**

[image]

And when we check the properties it's showing the message **This server does not support changing file permission**.

[image]

Are there any settings to set in order to open the file from **Explorer** after connecting to the **FTP**

**Any help on this?**

Comment: inb4 data breach

Comment: @Gantendo What?

Comment: If you rightclick the .xslx file, do you see an option called "Open With". If so, click "Choose another app". Choose Microsoft Excel and make sure "always use this app" is selected.

Comment: @Gantendo No, we do not have the option "Open With".

Comment: and if you make a temporary copy of one of those files on your desktop and try it there?

Comment: @Gantendo If copied to somewhere (other than FTP) it's opening. As I mentioned in the thread if open the file from **Local Drive** or **Share folder** it's opening. My question is why we are unable to open from explorer after connecting to **FTP**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145597/discussion-between-bojjaiah-and-gantendo).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it is **FTP**. However, for other than network users example clients/customers it is FTP. For local network users, it is a shared folder and for server-logged users, it is a Local folder.